# Leg glute pushdown vs. leg press for glutes?

Tags: glutes

I recently started leg glute pushdown using a Gravitron in order to develop my bottom a bit. I don't understand one thing though: what's the difference between this and leg presses? It feels pretty much like the exact same move with simply a different angle. Why would the pushdown version target the glutes better?

Comment: What's a Gravitron? The images I find by googling can't be the machine you're talking about.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gj-on_u61JE

Comment: Ah, I see. I've always wondered by people use the assisted dip/pullup station like that. I mean, I get what they're doing, but why not do squats instead?

Comment: Add in some barbell hip thrusts for the best glutes development.

Comment: All these ways to get out of squats/deads.

Answer (score 1):

This machine is moving the glute through a bigger range of motion than a leg press machine, where the glute does not maximally contract (maximum hip angle is only about 90 degrees, which is at the top of the motion).